# Setting value dynamically to a TextView of included view

Tags: android, layout, include

I have two `views` layout_a.xml and layout_b.xml. 
Inside layout_a and layout_b, there is an `include` which include another view layout_header.xml. 
That layout_header contains a `textView` which *display login user name*. 
The user name is stored in a singleton class `User`.

How can I set the username once but not in every `activity` of my app that include layout_header.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass TextView and have it initialize the singleton.

Java:

```
public class UserTextView extends TextView{

    public UserTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        CharSequence username = User.getInstance().username
        setText(username);      
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<com.example.UserTextView 
 android:id="@+id/username"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```